# Expanding nested variable names

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch script that I'd like to be able to have variable names that are not defined ahead of time, in part.

For example:

```
set proj=ABC
set %proj%_folder=\\share\folder\
```

That's legal, and seems to work.  But, I don't know how to use that later.

I can do this:

```
echo %%%proj%_folder%%
```

And it will echo

> ABC_folder

And I can do this:

```
echo %ABC_Folder%
```

And it will echo

> \share\folder

But that doesn't resolve ABC_folder, and I can't seem to force it to further do so.  Is that possible to have %ABC_Folder% expand?

Comment: Got as far as wriitng the full question then figured it out - if someone else has a better explanation I'll happily accept it (especially if I'm not 100% right on how this works!)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible through [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).  Enclosing the variable name in `!` instead of `%` will expand it properly.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set  proj=ABC
set %proj%_folder=\\server\folder\

echo !%proj%_folder!
```